# Reading regional dates from Excel with NPOI

Tags: .net, excel, npoi

I've got some code that reads in an Excel sheet, using NPOI. Here's a sample:

```
var hssfworkbook = new NPOI.HSSF.UserModel.HSSFWorkbook(Data);

var sheet = hssfworkbook.GetSheetAt(0);
System.Collections.IEnumerator rows = sheet.GetRowEnumerator();

while (rows.MoveNext()) 
{
    // read a date from column 0
    var value = rows.Current.GetCell(0, MissingCellPolicy.RETURN_NULL_AND_BLANK);    
}
```

This code works fine for most dates, but if you format the date in excel as a regional date, then it doesn't work (the value returned is null)

[image]

I suspect there may be something in the API to deal with this, but I can't for the life of me work it out.

Anyone got a clue?